# Como paso parametro en funciones Javascript

Tags: javascript, parametros, funcion

Quiero que la función imprimir muestre los valores que se encuentran en otras funciones.

```js
function variable1() {
  a = 5
  imprimir(a)
}

function variable2() {
  b = 10
  imprimir(b)
}

function imprimir(a, b) {

  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)

}

imprimir()
```

Comment: Hola @daniel-briceño. Creo que te resultaría muy útil revisar algunos manuales para facilitar las cosas. Te sugiero: **[Tutoriales
Para principiantes completos de la web](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Tutorials)** en esa página vas a encontrar suficientes enlaces a todo lo que necesitas.

Comment: ¿En donde se van a definir las variables `a,b`? En el código que propones no hay definición. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

para que el código funcione, las variables que quieres imprimir deben estar al alcance (scope) de la función que imprime.

Existen varias formas de lograr eso, la más sencilla es crear las variables de manera global:

```js
var a;
var b;

function variable1() {
  a = 5;
  imprimir();
}
function variable2() {
  b = 10;
  imprimir();
}

function imprimir() {
  console.log("El valor de a es: ", a);
  console.log("El valor de b es: ", b);
}

imprimir(); // Debe mostrar undefined para ambas variables
variable1(); // Debe mostrar valor para a y undefined para b
variable2(); // Debe mostrar valor para a y b
```

Answer (score 2):

Aqui te dejo una manera de hacerlo diferente a la que ya te dejaron.

Explicacion: para usar las variables dentro de tu funcion hago que cuando se ejecuten retornen el valor de la variable, asi capturo variables de otras funciones.

```js
//Defino la funcion imprimir
function imprimir(a, b) {
    console.log(a)
    console.log(b)
}

//Defino mi funcion que define la variable 1
function variable1() {
    a = 5
    //Retorno a
    return a
}

//Defino mi funcion que define la variable 2
function variable2() {
    b = 10
    //Retorno b
    return b
}

//Capturo variables
var a = variable1()
var b = variable2()

//Ejecuto funcion
imprimir(a,b)
```